# Query returning empty association with NOT IN () and with IN ()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the models `Invitation` and `Person`. The attributes and relations important in this question are the following:

```
# has sponsor_id, referral_email
class Invitation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sponsor, class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :referral, class_name: 'Person',
                        foreign_key: :referral_email, primary_key: :email
  scope :pending, -> { where.not(referral_email: Person.select(:email).distinct) }
end

# has id, email
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sent_invitations, class_name: 'Invitation', 
                              foreign_key: :sponsor_id
  has_many :received_invitations, class_name: 'Invitation', 
                                  foreign_key: referral_email, 
                                  primary_key: :email
  has_many :referrals, class_name: 'Persona', through: :sent_invitations
  has_many :sponsors, class_name: 'Persona', through: :received_invitations
end
```

I found a record of `Invitation` which its `referral_email` was not present in the table `Person`, and its `sponsor_id` was of a valid `Person`.

**The scenario:** From the `@sponsor`, I tried to see how many `sent_invitations.pending` it had, but the query returned an empty relation:

```
@sponsor.sent_invitations.pending.count # => 0
```

But this is the result of other queries I run while trying to debug:

```
@sponsor.sent_invitations.count # => 1
@sponsor.referrals.count # => 0
@sponsor.sent_invitations.first.referral_email # => 'some_email@example.com'
Person.pluck(:email).include? @sponsor.sent_invitations.first.referral_email # => false
```

I inverted the condition of the `scope` of `Invitation` to the following:

```
scope :pending, -> { where(referral_email: Person.select(:email).distinct) }
```

But the intended query kept returning an empty relation

```
@person.sent_invitations.pending.count # => 0
```

**Does anyone know what may be happending?**

The code worked fine on testing and we found this problem in production.

**Queries**

Query of original try

```
SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."sponsor_id" = $1 AND ("invitations"."referral_email" NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT "person"."email" FROM "person"))
```

Query of second try

```
SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."sponsor_id" = $1 AND ("invitations"."referral_email" IN (SELECT DISTINCT "person"."email" FROM "person"))
```

Comment: Check the logs or call `to_sql` on `@sponsor.sent_invitations.pending.count` to see the generated query. Personally I thinks that thing with `not(email: Person..pluck)` is too unperformant too, I would add a boolean to an invitation and, when a user is created, I would search it's related invitations and set it to true, it would be a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks for the performance proposal. I would want to create a solution if I find this same problem in another case.

Comment: If the code works fine on one environments and does not work on the other, then the problem might not be related to the code. Do you have the same config on both environments? same postresql versions? maybe production environment has some kind of caching going on?

Comment: Both environments have `postgresql-9.5` I checked. The configuration is the same as we use staging to check everything before we push to production. I don't know what caching is nor how to check it. Why do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Cache is when rails save some results on memory and returns that instead of making the query again to make things faster. The easiest way to check if the query is cached is checking the logs, it says "CACHE" on the logs and the queries takes 0.0ms. I'm not saying that's the problem though, I was just suggesting things to check. You could run the queries right from Postgresql CLI to take Rails out from the middle, if the problem persists even with doing plain sql queries without rails then it's not a problem with the app but an postgresql problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some records in table `Persona` with `email: nil`. Deleting them made the query to work as expected:

```
@person.sent_invitations.pending.count # => 1
@person.sent_invitations.first.referral_email # => 'some_email@example.com'
@person.sent_invitations.pending.first.referral_email # => 'some_email@example.com'
```

The `scope` remained as it was originally:

```
scope :pending, -> { where.not(referral_email: Persona.select(:email).distinct) }
```

I will research why were the `nil` emails creating this behavior. Thanks for the help.